# Help for creating Evolus Pencil Stencils

Tags: prototyping, mockups

I want to create stencils like **Dojo.GUI** for [Evolus Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx). But its inbuilt stencil generator doesn't allow to set advanced properties. I can just make a new collection of images.

Please suggest any online/offline stencil generator for Evolus Pencil which can help to generate any type of stencil without (or with less) XML codding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any tool like that but what you can do

1. Generate stencil through inbuilt stencil generator
2. Do the modification in generated XML from the reference of other
   stencil's XML
3. You must have basic knowledge of [XUL](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/xul/)

Comment: Thanks, I had found a XUL editor. I hope it can help me to create stencils with less coding.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://code.google.com/p/evoluspencil/downloads/list?q=label:Stencil